# Find Invertible and NonInvertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Can someone help me to understand this problem? I don't know where to begin.

Find an invertible matrix $A$ and a noninvertible matrix $B$ both of which satisfy $$M^2=3M$$

Thanks,
Rusty

Comment: Can you solve the case when $M$ is a 1x1 matrix? (i.e., just numbers)

Comment: In a 1x1 matrix, [0] would be non-invertible?

Comment: @Russ that is indeed the case; $[0]$ has no inverse, after all.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Got it, thanks! Any suggestions on how I go about determining an invertible matrix that will work? I've set x^2 = 3x and found x=3. (Not sure if this is the right path though).

Comment: What about the matrix $[3]$?

Comment: I see, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment gives you a very good way of constructing the simplest possible example: an example of size $1$.

Another simple kind of matrix that is helpful to look at is a [diagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix).  For example, if we set
$$
D = \pmatrix{d_1&0\\0&d_2}
$$
then what values of $d_1,d_2$ make $D$ satisfy $D^2 = 3D$?  From there, we could note that a matrix that is [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to $D$ would have the same property.  That is, if $M = PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$, then $M^2 = 3M$.

Finally, you could try to classify all of the matrices satisfying the equation up to [Jordan Canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).  Once you're sufficiently familiar with this notion in linear algebra, you could prove that all matrices satisfying this equation must be **similar** to a matrix of the form 
$$
D = \pmatrix{d_1\\ &\ddots\\&&d_n}
$$
where each $d_i$ is equal to either $0$ or $3$.